# I want to start preparing for a job interviews for which i want to get a decent at solving DSA problems

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, dynamic-programming, greedy-algorithms

How to learn DSA if you are already working as a software engineer and have decent knowledge about development. Only thing that makes me procratinate is going over theories behind different data structures. I thinkg solving problems is fun but the begineer phase is really boring and after a year i have almost forgotten all the dsa techniques.

How to start learning it and What to focus on so you don't bored(I know this is relative depending on a person)?

I would really appreciate if anyone has some fun and interesting resources.

Comment: There are many ways to learn this material.  I think it's a matter of opinion about what is the best way, and as such I suspect this question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers.  What do others think?  Any votes from the community, one way or another?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is entirely a matter of opinion like the other commentor has said (though they are right, that it can be a bit opinionated or subjective, everyone finds different things easier/harder after all!).

Personally I've competed in a lot of algorithm-based contests since I was young, I've been a math tutor for 5+ years, and I've taken educational psychology classes in university to help myself "learn how to learn."

I think there are quite a few great and important tips that everyone needs to realize and learn about this field.

If you've already got a good amount of developer experience that's great, as you'll probably already be able to visualize a lot of the data-structures. And you've probably already implemented quite a lot of trees in your time (maybe even without realizing!). And you'll write clean code!

I think I might just have a couple of tips.

Tip 1: It's not useful to cover proofs completely!

Sure, it's amazing if you could prove to me from scratch how a Suffix Array  ([Learn about it here](https://cp-algorithms.com/string/suffix-array.html)) can be computed in O(N log N), but to be honest, as long as you can memorize how to code it, and you have the general instinctive understanding of how it generally works, it's better just to code it up and move on.

As you have to realize, I've met some real algorithm pros before, and over 90% of them will never memorize every single proof (there are quite literally potentially ~800 different variations of algorithms and problems that can show up in the University contests).

Of course, if you do have a great deal of understanding of the proofs behind some of them, then you'll be able to code it more easily, and probably better than tutorials online will show you. And some proofs are easy to understand.

But honestly, I'd say, when you read about a data-structure, it's less about proofs, and more just about understanding the properties of it.

An important step of the [Network Flow](https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/edmonds_karp.html#flow-network) algorithm, is that you keep finding any possible path from the source to sink for water to flow through, and then you push water down that path. That means that you can use any path-finding algorithm, to find the paths for you, whether it be dijkstra, breadth-first search, DFS. Replacing the path-finding algorithm will change the complexity, which is important to learn, but you don't need to be able to calculate this complexity on your own.

Overall if you find yourself too stuck, it's better to either --> move to an easier variation of the algorithm/problem OR find a question where you can implement the algorithm, and just code it up and move on. Imagine it this way: It took humanity hundreds of years to come up with some of these algorithms, why would you be expected to be able to completely understand it, and recreate it from scratch in a single lesson?

The more problems you do, and the more practice you get, the better you'll be at it.

Tip 2: Don't trust all the code you see on the internet

I think there's a lot of just generally garbage code out there. Sure, there's a lot of working code out there, but is it clean? Does it have a lot of unnecessary code to it? I mean, even in my lectures at university, for Network Flow, we got shown the variation of the algorithm where you keep two copies of the same graph. One being the original, and other being the residual. But for most applications IRL and in contests for Network Flow, keeping a duplicate copy of the graph is both unnecessary, and doesn't give you a real understanding of the algorithm anyway.

Because of what I wrote in Tip 1, you'll find a lot of resources that are just clearly copy-pasted code, and don't give a real understanding of the algorithm. Or are over-engineered, or are just written uncleanly.

For the concepts and algorithms I thoroughly understand, I tend to write much cleaner, and more easily understandable code than most tutorials I've seen.

You'll find a lot of tutorials like this as well, where it feels like the person is just reading a script, and not giving you a real understanding of the concepts.

Please, for these reasons, avoid copy-pasting the code, try to walk through it step-by-step. But of course, it is going to be hard sometimes, and sometimes, if it's small enough, it's better to move on.

It only makes sense though, as when we get to this stage of Science, the topics become more and more niche, with lesser and lesser readily available resources.

Tip 3: For similar reasons above, do not learn to implement every data-structure from sratch. Instead, just learn the STD Library!

Lets say you enter a contest, and there's a very easy question where they want you to implement a priority-queue (or max-heap is it's other name). Do you need to understand the proof behind a priority-queue? Or how it's implemented from scratch?

Usually no. Both Python and C++ have an in-built priority-queue library, and you just have to learn about how to use that library. This will save you a lot of time. Similarly for a Binary Search. I would never usuaully implement a Binary Search myself (Though it's the easiest one to understand), as there's already a library for it in Python and C++.

All the contests allow these libraries, you can use them, and you will get full marks either way. So no need to reinvent the wheel.

Tip 4: Just have fun, and practice on contests.

I like [code forces](https://codeforces.com/) as it has a ranked mode, and it can be competitive. Plus you can just google resources as you're doing the contests, and not take it too seriously. Leetcode is the new popular website over the last 4 years, I don't like it as it costs money, but, if you're willing to pay for it, I think it might be better for learning.

And anyway, that's the best way to learn algorithms right, give a question a go, and if you can't do it, google for the algorithm it might be, and if you still can't do it, just look at the answers, and learn from them.

The only final thing I can tell you, is that Google is your friend. Which I'm sure you were already aware of. Never be scared to Google for what you don't know, and don't think of it as "I'm not learning it right." Any progress, even the smallest amount, is great progress, and an amazing day.

There are many online resources to learn from, including CodeForces, LeetCode, HackerRank, GeeksForGeeks, StackExchange, cp-algorithms. They are all great, so no need to be loyal to one. And all of them have their own pros and cons.

Comment: I'll just add a few things to this great answer. First, if you want to get used to interview questions, Sean Prashad's Leetcode Patterns might be something you would be interested in. Second, if you want a comprehensive yet accessible book on the topic, I would recommend Steven Halim's Competitive Programming 4, this is often more in-depth than online resources, yet full of practical knowledge and without unnecessary rigor you would expect from CLRS' Introduction to Algorithms.

Comment: Wow yes I fully agree. Competitive Programming was a great book, it's been so long for me though, I was learning from the older book Competitive Programming 3 :0

Comment: The new Competitive Programming 4 is much more comprehensive with a decade in development, they even split it into two books.

Comment: Thats really great answer. I will surely start working on things you recommended. I am too an enthusiast of "Learning How to learn" you can drop your LinkedIn or follow on mine. https://www.linkedin.com/in/hardikdhuri/ Would really like to talk about on this topic

Answer (score 2):

For data structures you need to learn - stack, queue, linked list, and binary search tree. These 4 should be enough for interviews. You can google them and you will know how to implement them.

There are some other data structures as well - set, multiset, map, multimap, etc. but I doubt if you will be asked to write code for them. But obviously, you may be asked questions like - what is a map?, etc. So, google these up too.

For algorithms, I would advise you to read the following book: The Design and Analysis of Computer Algorithms by Aho, Hopcroft, and Ullman.

You can also look at the following wikipedia pages:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_algorithms

I am listing some common data structures and algorithms questions asked in the interviews:

- Reverse a linked list.
- Add and delete an element in a linked list.
- Add and delete an element in a sorted linked list.
- Insert and delete an element in a binary search tree.
- Implement stack using linked list.
- Implement queue using linked list.
- Convert a linked list into a tree (each node of the list has an extra pointer).
- Convert a binary search tree into a linked list also (each node of the tree has an extra pointer).
- Implement quicksort.
- Implement mergesort.
- Implement a string search algorithm.

There are many more questions and you can find them on Internet.

Lastly, write code / practice coding as much as possible because interviews and software industry is all about coding, coding, and coding.

There are many coding websites on Internet like - https://www.codechef.com/, https://www.topcoder.com/, etc.